# Building a solution including an F# project using a build service on a windows server with F# runtime 2.0

Tags: f#, tfsbuild, build-definition

I am trying to make work the TFS 2010 build service (on a Windows Server SP2). The solution I want to get built includes many C# projects and one F# project. On my own PC, where I have Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 (Version 10.0.40219.1 SP1Rel, Microsoft .NET Framework, Version 4.0.30319 SP1Rel) installed with F#, I can build the solution.
When I created my TFS Build definition (Via Team Explorer -> right click 'All Build Definitions' -> 'New Build Definition') I only selected default stuff and specified a drop folder on a server share.

On the server I have installed the VS 2010 F# Runtime 2.0 from http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=13450

When queuing the build it runs for a while and then outputs the following error:
 C:\Builds\1\Processing\SM0021\Sources\Processing\Libraries\Syntune.Math\Release\Syntune.Math.FSharp\Syntune.Math.FSharp.fsproj (39): The imported project "C:\Program Files\Microsoft F#\v4.0\Microsoft.FSharp.Targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the  declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.

I do not know whether the build definition needs to specify how the Build Service should find the F# runtime, if I need to install some other F# package/distribution or if I must do something else. Or if this simply cannot be accomplishe dby a TFS build service.

Is this related to the F# runtime or is it something wrong with my build definition?
Can I copy files from my PC to the server and register them in the GAC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "F# runtime" does not include a compiler (and it also doesn't include `targets` file for MS BUILD).

If you can do that, then the easiest option would be to install Visual Studio with F# on the build machine. If that's not an option, you can try installing [standalone version of F#](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=18706), which includes a compiler. However, I'm not sure if the TFS build service will find this installation automatically.

Comment: If it can't find it automatically you can specify the path for the targets file in the build script. Have it running on TeamCity this way with a MSBuild script so I'm guessing it can be done with TFS as well

Comment: Thanks Tomas, This helped. The standalone version was installed and the build ran to completion. Obviously the service did find it.